# dtexec /val /proj my.ispac /pack my.dtsx /rep v returns immediately without any messages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, dtexec

I'm trying to setup a command-line call to dtexec to validate packages, using the project model.  I'm calling dtexec like this:

```
dtexec /val /proj my.ispac /pack my.dtsx  /rep v
```

Though the real paths to the ispac and dtsx are longer.  WHen I run this, all I see on the console is:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 11.0.7001.0 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Started:  10:40:01 AM
PS D:\>
```

The whole thing runs in under a second which leads me to believe that it did nothing.  And no messages of any kind are issued., even though I asked for verbose reporting.

Any ideas out there as to how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

My error is that the package parameter should be the name of the package only, without the "dtsx" extension.  When I changed that, it worked as expected.